# Dividir valor no foreach

Tags: php

Preciso pegar o valor de dois arrays diferentes e colocar no banco de dados, tentei com o código abaixo, mas estou com dificuldade para separar os dois valores e adicionar cada um dos valores a seus respectivos campos do banco de dados.

```
<?php

$array = array(12.1, 12.3, 18.32, 12.45, 1.5, 1.5);
$array2 = array(12.3, 2.3);

foreach(array_combine($array, $array2) as $key => $media) {
 $media = str_replace(",",".",$media); 
 $media_total = str_replace(",",".",$media_total); 
 var_dump($key, $media);
 var_dump($key, $media_total);
}
?>
```

Comment: Porque não faz um loop pra cada um?

Comment: O tem nos array?

Comment: Respectiva tabela ou quis dizer respectivos campos?

Comment: Quis dizer nos campos mesmo

Comment: Um array possui o valor de media simples e o outro possui o calculo com todas as medias

Comment: Como necessita que estes valores sejam colocados no banco? Tem algum padrão?

Comment: não entendi você tem 2 arrays, tem duas variaveis $media e $media_total esta com dificuldade em fazer a media ou de colocar no banco o valor das variaveis?

Comment: Minha dificuldade está em recuperar o valor dos dois arrays, só consigo recuperar de um

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tire o array_combine de dentro do foreach, pois para cada interação ele está combinando os arrays novamente.